# compare data from article to button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a "quiz" page where a user can guess if an article is real or fake. I have data-info from my database that I am trying to compare with the data-info for a button clicked by the user to check if they are correct or not. For example, if the data-info of the article is true, and the user clicks the button with data-info true then alert " you're right" or whatever. Someone please help!!

```js
function loadArticle(){
    $.get("/api/article", function(response){

        $(".header").html(response[0].Headline);
        $("h1").attr("data-info", response[0].is_real);
        $(".body" ).html('<a target="_blank" href="${response[0].web_address}"> ${response[0].web_address} </a>');
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class = "row" id="answers">
    <button data-info="false"  type = "button" class = "fa-bounce fas fa-times col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-2" id="fake">
        FAKE
    </button>
    <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
    <button data-info="true" type = "button" class = "fa-bounce fas fa-check col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-2" id="real">
        REAL
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the actual problem you are facing, your question does not have a question?

Comment: Please be more specific with your question. It's hard to understand what your problem is exactly. There are no `h1` elements in the HTML you provided, we don't know, why you're trying to set anchor href to a jQuery object, etc.. The function itself isn't even complete..

Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I apologize, brand new here in the dev world so I am trying to get the hang of stack overflow. My question is, how do I write an if statement that when the data info from my h1 tag (which is applied through .attr() with jQuery) matches the data info assigned to my buttons an alert gets prompted. I am not sure if that is any clearer but hopefully so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare `data-*` with the jQuery method [.data()](https://api.jquery.com/data/)

here is an example when you get the data from the api request and compare its value when you click on the "real" button for example:

```
<button id="real" data-info="true">
real
</button>

<button id="real" data-info="false">
fake
</button>

var dataToCompare;
function loadArticle(){
  $.get("/api/article", function(response){
     dataToCompare = response[0].is_real;
  }
}

$('#real').click(function() {
 var data = $(this).data('info');

 if(data === dataToCompare) {
    alert('yes');
  }
})
```